# Dynamically get all properties of particular field

Tags: apex, dynamic

My requirement is : I have to dynamically get all properties of particular field e.g :

```
Map <String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = schemaMap.get('Account').getDescribe().fields.getMap();   
Schema.DescribeFieldResult dfield = fieldMap.get('AccountNumber').getDescribe();
```

Now i have to collect `Schema.DescribeFieldResult`  in collection like map or somthing

Output should be somehow like this

```
getSoapType -> STRING, getSobjectField->AccountNumber, getType->STRING
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you are looking for here...

You could use JSON:

```
String s = JSON.serialize(Account.AccountNumber.getDescribe());
System.debug(s);
```

that outputs this:

> {"autoNumber":false,"byteLength":120,"calculated":false,"calculatedFormula":null,"cascadeDelete":false,"caseSensitive":false,"controllerName":null,"createable":true,"custom":false,"defaultValue":null,"defaultValueFormula":null,"defaultedOnCreate":false,"dependentPicklist":false,"deprecatedAndHidden":false,"digits":0,"displayLocationInDecimal":false,"externalId":false,"extraTypeInfo":null,"filterable":true,"filteredLookupInfo":null,"groupable":true,"htmlFormatted":false,"idLookup":false,"inlineHelpText":null,"label":"Account
>   Number","length":40,"mask":null,"maskType":null,"name":"AccountNumber","nameField":false,"namePointing":false,"nillable":true,"permissionable":true,"picklistValues":[],"precision":0,"queryByDistance":false,"referenceTargetField":null,"referenceTo":[],"relationshipName":null,"relationshipOrder":null,"restrictedDelete":false,"restrictedPicklist":false,"scale":0,"soapType":"xsd:string","sortable":true,"type":"string","unique":false,"updateable":true,"writeRequiresMasterRead":false}

And code like this will do that for every field (and could be wrapped in an outer loop to do it for every SObject):

```
Map <String, Schema.SObjectField> m = Account.getSobjectType()
        .getDescribe().fields.getMap();
for (SObjectField f : m.values()) {
    String s = JSON.serialize(f.getDescribe());
    System.debug(s);
}
```